# wsdl2java: override embedded schema with external xsd

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a wsdl and a bunch of xsd's from another service. The wsdl contains some embedded schemas, so that alle required datatypes are there.
But in the wsdl there are only "forward declarations", to ensure existence of the datatypes.

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://targetnamespace">
    <xs:element name="operationData">
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Then I have the following xsd (same targetNamespace and element name)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://targetnamespace">
    <xs:element name="operationData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                ...
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I now call

> wsdl2java -b operationData.xsd service.wsdl

The generation failes, because of *operationData* is defined in the xsd and the wsdl. 
If I ommit the xsd, generation succeeds, but the operation will just take an Object as parameter.

Is there a way to tell the wsdl2java generator to "override" the embedded schema if an external with the same namespace is available?